# Resturcturing json in python

Tags: python, json

I have the current json format:

```
data = [{'Content': 'This is the content', 'Title': 'Title1'},{'Content': 'I am content', 'Title': 'Title2'}, {'Content': 'This is more content', 'Title': 'Title3'}]
```

Want to convert it to the following format

```
data = {"Title":["Title1", "Title2", "Title3"], "Content":["This is the content","I am content","This is more content"]}
```

Comment: start by importing the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module, then code it

Comment: That looks like a python list of dicts, not JSON. JSON is a data interchange format. Something you'd serialize your python data to, for example for transport over the net. For your transformation look into using a dictionary comprehension over keys, with list comprehensions as values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate over your list and append each key, value pair to a new dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = [{'Content': 'This is the content', 'Title': 'Title1'},{'Content': 'I am content', 'Title': 'Title2'}, {'Content': 'This is more content', 'Title': 'Title3'}]
result = defaultdict(list)
for elem in data:
  for k,v in elem.iteritems():
    result[k].append(v)
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that's a big help!